# Is this matrix multiplication correct

Tags: matrices

Having two diagonal matrices $A$ and $D$ where ${\bf a}_i$ is a $M\times 1$ vector for $i\in[1:n]$ while $d_i$ is a scalar.

$$A  = \begin{bmatrix}
    {\bf a_1} & 0 & 0 & \dots  &0 \\
    0 & {\bf a}_{2} & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 &0 & 0 & \dots  & {\bf a}_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$D  = \begin{bmatrix}
    { d_1} & 0 & 0 & \dots  &0 \\
    0 & {d}_{2} & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 &0 & 0 & \dots  & { d}_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can I say that $$AD = \sum_i^{n} a_i d_i$$

Thanks.

Comment: What size are the vectors? Are they row vectors or are they column vectors? Is it actually possible to perform this multiplication? And what is the $x_{2n}$ in the $A$ matrix?

Comment: You cannot say that, since $a_id_i$ is a vector, and $AD$ is a matrix.

Comment: I have edited @BenS. there was typo. Thanks

Comment: If $a_i$ is a $M\times 1$ vector, then $A$ is not a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $AD$ is not equal to $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_id_i$$

For every $i$, the value $a_id_i$ is a **vector** (of dimension $M\times 1$). Therefore, the sum of such vectors is also a $M\times 1$ vector.

On the other hand, since $A$ is a $M\times n$ matrix and $D$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, the matrix $AD$ is also a $M\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Notice that you are multiplying an $M\times n$ matrix by an $n\times n$ matrix, so you should get back an $M\times n$ matrix, but $\sum_i^n \mathbf{a}_id_i$ is an $M\times 1$ matrix, i.e. a vector.